# Why is my function stripping the dir attribute despite it being in my list of allowed attributes?

Tags: python, html

I am using the bleach package to strip away invalid html. I am puzzled why the `dir` attribute is being stripped from my string. Is `dir` not an attribute, or could it just be that the package does not support `dir`?

I have included the entire script, so you can run it for your convenience.

```
import bleach

string = """<p dir="rtl">asdasdasd <span>asdasdasd</span> asdsadasdsad .<br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>"""


def strip_invalid_html(html):
    """ strips invalid tags/attributes """

    allowed_tags = [
        'p', 'a', 'blockquote',
        'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5',
        'strong', 'em',
        'br',
        'span',
    ]

    allowed_attributes = {
        'a': ['href', 'title'],
        'dir': ['rtl', 'ltr']
    }

    cleaned_html = bleach.clean(
        html,
        attributes=allowed_attributes,
        strip=True,
        tags=allowed_tags
    )

    print(cleaned_html)

strip_invalid_html(string)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you pass a dict for `attributes`, the dict should map tag names to allowed attribute names, not map attribute names to allowed attribute values.

If you want `'dir'` to be an allowed attribute for `p` tags, you need a `'p': ['dir']` entry, not a `'dir': ['rtl', 'ltr']` entry:

```
allowed_attributes = {
    'a': ['href', 'title'],
    'p': ['dir'],
}
```